# Why same css can't add a new line for input element?

Tags: html, css, newline

It a smarty way to add a new line before every span tag.

```css
span {
    display: inline;
}
span:before {
    content: "\a ";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>
  First line.<span>Next line.</span> <span>Next line.</span>
</p>
```

Now as the same way ,i want to add a new line at the end of every `input` element,why no new line for the `input` element?

```css
input{
    display:inline;
}
input::after{  
    content:"\a ";
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
content:<input id="1th" type="text" >
content:<input id="3th" type="text" >
content:<input id="4th" type="text" >
```

Comment: Because `::before` and `::after` add content within the element, and inputs can't have any content within their element. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: can i add a new line with css for the input element? `<br/>` can do ,but i want a css way.

Comment: input have no enclosed tags wont work with ::after

Comment: You could wrap the content with a semantic `<label>` element and set the label to block or inline block. E.g. `<label>content:<input id="1th" type="text" /></label>`

Comment: Why are you not just changing it to be a block element? `input{
        display:block;
    }`

Comment: @epascarello Then the inputs would be on their own line instead of next to the text.

Comment: Well I would change the mark up. Only other option would be have to use JavaScript to alter the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've explicitly set your input's `display` property as `inline`.

An inline element does not start on a new line.

---

**Solution**:

A block-level element always starts on a new line

Change the input selector `display` property value to `block`.

```css
input{
    display:block;
}
input::after{  
    content:"\a ";
    white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
content:<input id="1th" type="text" >
content:<input id="3th" type="text" >
content:<input id="4th" type="text" >
```

---

*All of this is unnecessary*, every HTML element is either a `block element` or an `inline element`. It turns out that the `input` element is a block element, making this CSS declaration redundant.